# Display unit count in Laravel blade template

Tags: php, laravel, count

I want to show total count of the unit so I wrote `{{ ($unit->unit_id)->count() }}` to return the data.
**blade.php**

```
         <tbody>
            @foreach($developer as $key => $data)
            <tr>
                <td></td>  
                <td>{{$data->developer_name}}</td>
                <td>
                    @foreach($data->projects as $key => $project)
                    <a href="">{{ $project->project_name }}</a><br>
                    @endforeach
                </td>
                <td>
                    @foreach($data->projects as $key => $project)
                    @foreach($project->phase as $key => $phase)
                    @foreach($phase->unit as $key => $unit)

                    <a href="">{{ ($unit->unit_id)->count() }}</a><br> //error

                    @endforeach
                    @endforeach
                    @endforeach

                </td>

            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
```

**UPDATE:**

**Unit.php Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Unit extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table="pams_unit";
    protected $primaryKey="unit_id";
}
```

**UnitController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Unit;
use App\Developer;


class UnitByDeveloperController extends Controller
{
    //
     public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function show(Request $request){

        $dev_id = $request->input('dev_id');
        $developer =Developer::where(function($query1) use($dev_id){
            if($dev_id){
                $query1
                ->where('id',$dev_id);  
            }
        })
        ->active()
        ->paginate('8');



        return view('reportlayout.unitByDeveloper',compact('developer'));

    }

}
```

But, an error is showing :-

> Call to a member function count() on integer

Anyone can help me to spot my mistake ?

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
{{ ($unit->unit_id)->count() }}
```

To:

```
{{ $unit->count() }}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it do not solve my problem. Error : `Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded`

Comment: Then add your controller's code in question's description.

Comment: Model and controller added.

Comment: So it works. The problem is: there is too much loop in this blade. The server needs more time to execute those. In your `php.ini` maximum execution time set to 30 seconds. Edit the `php.ini` file if you can.